MAGMA: How to efficiently do coercion of element of HomGrp to element of GrpAuto?
Suppose I have a finite $p$-group $G$ as GrpPC in MAGMA. The computation of the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ takes a very long time.
Suppose that I also have an endomorphism $\alpha$ of G which is bijective (this is of course an automorphism then).
$\alpha$ is stored as type HomGrp, but elements of AutomorphismGroup(G) are stored as elements in GrpAuto (i.e. GrpAutoElt).
However, coercion of $\alpha$ in the form of AutomorphismGroup(G)!alpha also takes a very long time. Is the whole automorphism group of $G$ calculated for the coercion procedure?
Can I change the type of $\alpha$ from HomGrp to GrpAutoElt without the lengthy computation? I haven't found a clue in the MAGMA handbook.

Yes, here is an example. It is in the manual.
> G := SmallGroup(12,3); //Alt(4)
> A:=AutomorphismGroup(G, [G.1,G.2,G.3], [[G.1^2, G.3, G.2]]);
> Type(A.1);
GrpAutoElt
> A.1;
Automorphism of GrpPC : G which maps:
    G.1 |--> G.1^2
    G.2 |--> G.3
    G.3 |--> G.2


Thank you very much! May I ask you where one finds this example in the online handbook? I cannot find it as an example there (searched for SmallGroup and AutomorphismGroup).

I didn't mean the example was in the handbook - I made up the example myself. The description of the function is at the bottom of the page here.
